# Do you have commit webpack generated files?

Tags: node.js, git, webpack

I started using webpack with my node application recently. However, the application generates a huge file in `client/dist/js/app.js` and commiting that file everytime takes quite a bit of time. I imagine, that as my web application keeps growing, its going to get even worse.

The question is, since you can always run `npm run bundle`, which will run webpack locally and generate all the required files, do you actually have to commit the entire directory generated by webpack? Is it considered good or bad practice doing that?

Comment: No. **Never** commit built/compiled files of any sort to git.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your file is a minified javascript generated from your source code by webpack. You must not include these generated files from the dist folder in your repository since they will be overwritten every time you run webpack after changes has been made to your source files.

Remove this directory from your repository and write `dist/` in a `.gitignore` file to avoid adding it again next time.

Comment: yeah, thanks. To enable webpack I followed some online tutorials and they never metioned any thing about tracking the file. Intuitively, I thought the same thing as what you said, just wanted to confirm.